# Struts2-jQuery datepicker automatically changing format

Tags: jquery, struts2, datepicker

The date picker is declared as below

```
<sj:datepicker title="%{getText('Choose_to_date')}" value="%{#attr.endDate}"
```

Now, when the value passed is something like 09/01/2013 when the page loads it automatically changes to 01/09/2013
This behavior is not seen if the value being set is 09/28/2013
i.e. if the number representing day > 12, all works fine.

Printed the value of attr.endDate into the logs and it shows up correctly

Been stuck with this issue for a day now :-(

Comment: http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/formatting-dates-and-numbers.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `displayFormat` attribute:

```
<sj:datepicker title="%{getText('Choose_to_date')}" value="%{#attr.endDate}" displayFormat="dd/mm/yyyy">
```

Or whatever format suits you.

Comment: Thanks, helped me close out a long pending issue.